# Sony Vaio Backlight

Tags: 18.04, backlight, vaio, sony

Already posted in Community, but got locked and moved, and got lost, sorry.

Here's the issue:

I'm using Ubuntu in a Sony Vaio SVF15A17CLB, which has a backlit keyboard, but it's not turned on by the System by default,  so, every time I want to turn it on I have to manually change the value in:
`/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight`
from -1 to 1 with `sudo vi`

But that resets every time I restart the computer.

Is it a setting somewhere else handling that? Can I make it permanent?

Comment: That looks like the answer. But now I have the problem that I don't have a `rc.local` file

Comment: Just added the file and boom! like a charm. Thanks!
One detail, though, changed the `>>` operator to a `>`, since I want to write, not append.

Comment: Thank you very much for the way the question was posed, helped me with my VAIO too!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put the comment into an actual answer, you can create an `rc.local` file or add it to the end of your existing file. It should look something like this:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight
exit 0
```

You want to make sure you're using `>` and not `>>`, since you want to overwrite the backlight value, not append to it.

You could probably create a systemd service file that would do the same thing, but I'm not sure if that's really necessary.

Comment: I get a permission denied message when I try to execute the "echo 1 ..." command as a root user. How to overcome this?

Comment: I'm not sure. You might just have the the wrong libraries installed.